# validator for repeated ndb.StructuredProperty fails to fire

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Here is my ndb Model

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from mainsite.rainbow.models.CFCSocialUser import CFCSocialUser


class CFCSocialGroup(ndb.Model):

    def remove_duplicate(self, value):
        raise Exception("Duplicate user detected")

    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    created_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    created_by = ndb.StructuredProperty(CFCSocialUser)
    members = ndb.StructuredProperty(CFCSocialUser, repeated=True, validator=remove_duplicate)

    @staticmethod
    def create_group(name):
        """Create a new group"""
        group = CFCSocialGroup(name=name)
        return group

    def add_member(self, social_user):
        """Add a member to the local group"""
        self.members.append(social_user)
```

I am trying to ensure that I do not add the same user to a given group. So I trying to validate the value of members property (StructuredProperty).

My tests is

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mainsite.rainbow.models.CFCSocialGroup import CFCSocialGroup
from tests.test_CFCSocialUser import create_user
from tests.cfcsocialtests.testbase import CFCTestBase_NDB
from nose.tools import *
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr


class TestCFCSocialGroup(CFCTestBase_NDB):
    @attr("CRUD")
    @raises(Exception)
    def test_duplicate_addition(self):
        """Test to detect duplicate users in groups"""
        user1 = create_user()
        user2 = create_user()
        group = CFCSocialGroup.create_group('Group1')
        group.add_member(user1)
        group.add_member(user2)
```

The test fails to raise an exception.

Here is the debug code

```
    FAILED (errors=1)
MacBook-Pro:tests vinay$ nosetests -v test_CFCSocialGroup.py
Test to detect duplicate users in groups ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: Test to detect duplicate users in groups
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/tools/nontrivial.py", line 67, in newfunc
    raise AssertionError(message)
AssertionError: test_duplicate_addition() did not raise Exception
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: DEBUG: Using threading.local
root: WARNING: No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator put(context.py:787)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet): creating new queue for ('set', 32, '', None)
root: DEBUG: initial generator put(context.py:787) yielded <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:810); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec250 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d0ec490>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: memcache.Set
root: DEBUG: Sending {'NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw': 1} to suspended generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1122)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); result True>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1122) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec250 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); result True>
root: DEBUG: Sending True to suspended generator put(context.py:810)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec510 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet): creating new queue for None
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:810) yielded <Future 10d0ec510 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:824); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ec510 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _finished_callback
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec610 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _put_tasklet(context.py:348); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _put_tasklet(context.py:348)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _put_tasklet(context.py:348) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d0ec890>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: datastore_v3.Put
root: DEBUG: Sending [Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')] to suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:358)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec510 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:358) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec610 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _put_tasklet(context.py:348); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ec510 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
root: DEBUG: Sending Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph') to suspended generator put(context.py:824)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet): creating new queue for (0, '', None)
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:824) yielded <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:833); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _finished_callback
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec850 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d0ec210>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: memcache.Delete
root: DEBUG: Sending [2] to suspended generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1141)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); result 2>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1141) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec850 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); result 2>
root: DEBUG: Sending 2 to suspended generator put(context.py:833)
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:833) returned Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0d2e90 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _finished_callback
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator put(context.py:787)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ec990 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet): creating new queue for ('set', 32, '', None)
root: DEBUG: initial generator put(context.py:787) yielded <Future 10d0ec990 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:810); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ec990 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ecd10 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d0ecf50>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: memcache.Set
root: DEBUG: Sending {'NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw': 1} to suspended generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1122)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec990 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); result True>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1122) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ecd10 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_set_tasklet(context.py:1111); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ec990 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_set_tasklet).add(('NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw', 0), ('set', 32, '', None)); result True>
root: DEBUG: Sending True to suspended generator put(context.py:810)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0ecfd0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet): creating new queue for None
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:810) yielded <Future 10d0ecfd0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:824); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ecfd0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _finished_callback
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d132110 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _put_tasklet(context.py:348); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _put_tasklet(context.py:348)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _put_tasklet(context.py:348) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d132450>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: datastore_v3.Put
root: DEBUG: Sending [Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')] to suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:358)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ecfd0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:358) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d132110 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _put_tasklet(context.py:348); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10d0ecfd0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_put_tasklet).add(CFCSocialUser(key=Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph'), date_of_birth=datetime.date(1900, 3, 2), email='vinay@vinayjoseph.com', username='Vinay Joseph'), None); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
root: DEBUG: Sending Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph') to suspended generator put(context.py:824)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet): creating new queue for (0, '', None)
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:824) yielded <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787) suspended generator put(context.py:833); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _finished_callback
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet): 1 items
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 10d0eca10 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130); pending>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130)
root: DEBUG: initial generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x10d0ece10>
root: DEBUG: idler: _on_idle
root: DEBUG: idler _on_idle removed
root: DEBUG: rpc: memcache.Delete
root: DEBUG: Sending [2] to suspended generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1141)
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); result 2>
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1141) returned None
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0eca10 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1130); result None>
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion
root: DEBUG: <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 10b0ae1d0 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyHwsSDUNGQ1NvY2lhbFVzZXIiDFZpbmF5IEpvc2VwaAw, (0, '', None)); result 2>
root: DEBUG: Sending 2 to suspended generator put(context.py:833)
root: DEBUG: suspended generator put(context.py:833) returned Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 10d0ec150 created by _put_async(model.py:3467) for tasklet put(context.py:787); result Key('CFCSocialUser', 'Vinay Joseph')>
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.035s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this code in `models.py`:

```
class Member(ndb.Model):

    name = ndb.StringProperty()


def remove_duplicates(prop, value):
    raise Exception('Duplicate')


class Club1(ndb.Model):

    members = ndb.StructuredProperty(Member, repeated=True, validator=remove_duplicates)
```

I can create a `Member` instance

`> m = Member(name='Alice')`

creating a `Club1` instance with this `Member` instance triggers the validation:

```
> c1 = models.Club1(members=[m])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
  File "models.py", line 60, in remove_duplicates
    raise Exception('Duplicate')
Exception: Duplicate
```

However, creating an empty `Club1` instance and then appending a `Member` does not: this is effectively your test case.

```
> c1 = models.Club1()
> c1.members.append(m)
> c1.put()
Key('Club1', 6682831673622528)
```

We can subclass `ndb.StructuredProperty` and put the validation in the subclass:

```
class MembersStructuredProperty(ndb.StructuredProperty):

    def _validate(self, value):
        raise Exception('Duplicate')


class Club2(ndb.Model):

    members = MembersStructuredProperty(Member, repeated=True)
```

Creating a `Club2` instance with a `Member` triggers the validation as before:

```
> c2 = models.Club2(members=[m])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
  File "models.py", line 56, in _validate
    raise Exception('Duplicate')
Exception: Duplicate
```

And now so does appending a `Member` and then trying to write to the Datastore:

```
> c2 = models.Club2()
> c2.members.append(m)
> c2.put()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
  File "models.py", line 56, in _validate
    raise Exception('Duplicate')
Exception: Duplicate
```

So subclassing `ndb.StructuredProperty` should allow your test to pass.

<del>I don't know why ndb's property validation behaves like this, arguably it's a bug, or at least undocumented behaviour.</del>

**EDIT:**

As @DanCornilescu observes in the comments, this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10622) in the SDK

Comment: Maybe related to: "When updating a repeated property, you can either assign it a new list or mutate the existing list in place" (from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#repeated)?

Comment: I suppose they want us to subclass everything.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you move the validation method outside of the class ?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Good spot; then OP's issue - validation not being triggered after append and put - looks like a bug in the SDK, as the put should trigger the validation.

Comment: @VinayJoseph validator functions [take the property being validated and its value as arguments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options).  If the validator function is a method on a model then the first argument it gets will be the model instance, not the property.  This doesn't matter if the validator doesn't use its first argument, but at the very least it misleads readers of the code, who would assume that the function operates on a model instance.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth scanning the open issues list :) See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10622

Comment: @DanCornilescu  Cool - I did check in fact, but only for 'StructuredProperty', so didn't find that one.